# SlimDX DXGI Factory finds no adapters in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, directx, slimdx

Title says it all. I'm getting my adapter in simple console app, but can't get it i my ASP.NET app. Adapter count shows 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wait... you're trying to create a directx device on the server side of a network connection? That won't work. DirectX works on a _local_ graphics card only. You don't want the server to show an image (on its screen!) based on a client request.

Comment: I don't want to show it on it's screen. I want to do some off-screen server-side map-tile rendering which is currently implemented with GDI. I'm testing whether hardware-accelerated rendering will give better performance than software rendering.

Comment: Btw, I have a graphics device on my web server.

Comment: Ni0ot sure this can work, because the IIS process hosting the Asp.Net service does not have access to the desktop, so maybe it cannot use the graphics card at all.